# The first formal parameter in an Ada procedure

Tags: ada

From Ada2012 Reference Manual:

arm2012.html/rm-4-1-3.html

A selected_component that is not an expanded name shall resolve to denote one of the following:

- A view of a subprogram whose first formal parameter is of a tagged type or is an access parameter whose designated type is tagged:

Why it is significant to have it only for the first formal parameter?

Please explain with examples.

Comment: That's how Ada implements `Object.Operation(...)` notation similar to what's available in other object-oriented languages.  Ada 95 didn't have this, so if you have an object of a tagged type, and an operation defined on that type, you had to say `The_Package.Operation(Object, other-parameters)` instead of `Object.Operation(other-parameters)`.

Answer (score 6):

The definition in [*4.1.3 Selected Components, 9.1/2*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-4-1-3.html) provides for [*prefixed notation*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-2-3.html), which allows one to invoke the primitive operations of a tagged type without mentioning the enclosing package explicitly. A related example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928561/230513).